# How to parse particular JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

To parse a JSON, as I found also on the web, I usually used this kind of code:

```
guard let results = receivedUserJSON["results"] as? [String: Any] else {
    print("Error interpreting results")
    return
}
```

This time I have a problem, because it seems to end in the else of this guard let. The JSON has the following structure:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "gender": "female",
        "name": {
            "title": "mrs",
            "first": "silene",
            "last": "almeida"
        },
        "location": {
            "street": "2594 rua maranhão ",
            "city": "pouso alegre",
            "state": "distrito federal",
            "postcode": 20447,
            "coordinates": {
                "latitude": "-70.0198",
                "longitude": "123.6577"
            },
            "timezone": {
                "offset": "+4:30",
                "description": "Kabul"
            }
        },
        "email": "silene.almeida@example.com",
        "login": {
            "uuid": "d06a46b3-1c00-42be-b8fc-d271bf901f7d",
            "username": "silversnake251",
            "password": "ventura",
            "salt": "UcckU6RG",
            "md5": "7c8c4129587c61da01ca7cf4f88353c5",
            "sha1": "6cbf7ec377ff4ebad5a392ec487343bf613858ef",
            "sha256": "8dedf3649fb833a1936b8885627b86c6cf02062eb74f727b2cbd674a30f73e75"
        },
        "dob": {
            "date": "1969-07-13T00:58:26Z",
            "age": 49
        },
        "registered": {
            "date": "2003-09-28T09:44:56Z",
            "age": 15
        },
        "phone": "(95) 0094-8716",
        "cell": "(20) 1014-3529",
        "id": {
            "name": "",
            "value": null
        },
        "picture": {
            "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/66.jpg",
            "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/66.jpg",
            "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/66.jpg"
        },
        "nat": "BR"
    }],
    "info": {
        "seed": "dd971cddf636d2d7",
        "results": 1,
        "page": 1,
        "version": "1.2"
    }
}
```

What should I do to properly parse this JSON? I would prefer not to go for the Codable solution because I don't need all of these values.

PS: I know the json is correct because I tried and printed it with:

```
if let JSONString = String(data: responseData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
    print(JSONString)
}
```

Comment: Put a break point at the Guard Else and post the value of receivedUserJSON["results"] at that time

Comment: The Json is valid as you have mentioned. The problem is your results is an array of [String: Any] and you are parsing it as [String: Any]. Try,
 guard let results = receivedUserJSON["results"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
                print("Error interpreting results")
                return
            }
and this should get you the results.

Comment: Please look into using Swift `Codable` and actual models..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`results` is an array

```
guard let results = receivedUserJSON["results"] as? [[String:Any]] else {
            print("Error interpreting results")
            return
        }
```

I see no value for it to be an array as it contains 1 element so you may think to alter this json

current strucsture

```
{
    "results": [{}],
    "info": {
        "seed": "dd971cddf636d2d7",
        "results": 1,
        "page": 1,
        "version": "1.2"
    }
}
```

you may alter it to

```
{
    "results": {},
    "info": {
        "seed": "dd971cddf636d2d7",
        "results": 1,
        "page": 1,
        "version": "1.2"
    }

}
```

Comment: This solved it! Thank you very much. Can't change the structure of the JSON because I'm using some APIs though, thank you very much!

Comment: @Garu94 you may think of using **Codable** as well